# Doing something I'm not paid to do

Tags: work-experience

I'm a kitchen assistant, but I'm constantly asked to cook as well.
Having a low salary and with little hours, that still wasn't a problem for me.
Now that I did a course and I've got my degree that allows me to do a cook's job, I'm supposed to get a higher paycheck for it; but my boss is not on the same wavelength; so, what I'm supposed to do ? We desperately need another chef, but the company would not hire one, as they have a "stupid" to do that for less pay. Thanks

Comment: Seems obvious. Stop being a "stupid". Find another restaurant that needs a chef.

Comment: Bingo.  Go to your manager once, say that we need a chef, and you would like to be promoted into that role.  If he agrees; you're good.  If not; then the next time you talk about the chef position would be when you hand in your resignation.

Comment: Right now this reads like a rant, and it is unclear what your goal is. Consider editing your post to make your question more clear. Remember, [Real questions have answers](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2696#2696).

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the way the world works.  You will likely have to change employers in order to advance.  Recently graduating is a very valid reason to be considered for a higher position at another employer.  Best of luck to you!

Comment: Take the responsibility has a learning experience.  At some point translate this to a job elsewhere or a raise at your current.  If it means working a lot harder such that you are just plain more worn out by the end of the shift then I get demanding a raise up front.

Answer (score 15):

Congratulations, you've progressed from kitchen assistant to cook. Most managers don't take ultimatums well, so you need to ask yourself what you really want. Getting a raise to cook where you are would be great, but is the *raise* part or the *where you are* part more important?

If it's where you are, ask now for a raise and if you get a yes, terrific. If you don't, oh well, at least you're cooking and you get to stay somewhere familiar.

If it's the raise part, ask now for a raise and if you get anything other than a yes (including "we'll see, maybe in a few months when business is better") make a sad face and say that you're disappointed. No threats. Then quietly go and look for a new job. When you get one, tell your boss that you're leaving and be nice about it.

Very few people work in the same kitchen all their professional lives. Moving jobs for more money, better hours, more responsibility and so on will be your normal until you retire. You might as well get used to it. In the future, it won't always be your choice (restaurants close, business slumps and people are laid off, and so on) so you need some practice at finding and landing kitchen jobs. Now is a fine time to start, while your educational institution may be able to help.